# How can I permanently change the color of terminal's shell prompt and create new empty line after a command?

Tags: bash, terminal

Before I tried to make changes, I had `PS1="\n$PS1"`. I currently have `PS1="\e[0;34m[\u@ \W]\$ \e[m"` after my aliases in my `.bash_profile` but it's not giving me the behavior I want. When I'm writing a command and it reaches the end of the line before I finish, the terminal doesn't move on to the next line. Instead, it goes back to the beginning of the line I was working on and visually overwrites the bash prompt and anything after as I keep typing. How can I get the terminal to move onto a new line when it reaches the end of the previous line as well as make an empty line before/after every command?

I was trying to permanently change the bash prompt color to blue as well as create a new empty line after I run my command to make the terminal easier to read.

Thanks

Just realized I was looking at a guide for changing color for shell prompt on Linux when it should've been for Mac.

Comment: Try [apple.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at [this](https://github.com/vaniacer/info-bar) It's my varian of command promt with colors and git support

[image]

```
#!/bin/bash

case $1 in '--remove' | '-r') sed '/[oOº]_[oOº]/d' -i ~/.bashrc; exit 0;; esac

cat >> ~/.bashrc << 'EOF'
#---------------------------------------------{ Info bar }----------------------------------------------+ o_o
line_simbol='-'                                                                                       # | O_O
faces=(O_o o_O o_o O_O º_o º_O O_º o_º º_º); facesN=${#faces[@]} # Face types                         # | o_º
declare -A paint=( # Colors     |   Effects                                                           # | O_O
                [green]='\e[32m' [norm]='\e[0m'                                                       # | O_o
                [yelow]='\e[33m' [bold]='\e[1m'                                                       # | O_o
                 [blue]='\e[94m'  [dim]='\e[2m')                                                      # | o_o
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ º_O
face() { printf "${paint[yelow]}${faces[$((RANDOM % $facesN))]}${paint[norm]}"; } # Random face       # | º_º
info() {                                                                                              # | o_º
    [[ -d .git ]] && {  # If in git project folder add git status to info bar output                  # | O_o
        git_clr=('GIT' $(git -c color.ui=always status -sb)) # Colored output 4 info                  # | o_O
        git_tst=('GIT' $(git                    status -sb)) # Simple  output 4 test                  # | o_o
    }                                                                                                 # | o_o
                                                                                                      # | o_O
    nametest="{ $HOSTNAME }"                                                                          # | O_o
    sign="{ ${paint[norm]}$HOSTNAME${paint[green]} }"                                                 # | o_o
    printf -v line  "%${COLUMNS}s"; line=${line// /$line_simbol}                                      # | O_o
    printf -v line2 "%$[($COLUMNS-${#nametest})/2]s"; line2=${line2// /$line_simbol}                  # | O_O
    signtest="$line2{ $HOSTNAME }$line2"; [[ ${#signtest} -lt $COLUMNS ]] && sign+=$line_simbol       # | o_o
                                                                                                      # | o_o
    D=$(printf "%(%a %d %b %T)T")                             # Date & time                           # | O_o
    T=" O_o $PWD  ${git_tst[*]} $D o_O "                      # Test string                           # | o_o
    S=$[$COLUMNS-${#T}]; [[ $S -lt 0 ]] && S=0                # Count spaces                          # | o_º
    date="${paint[dim]}$D${paint[norm]}"                      # Date & time                           # | O_o
    line="${paint[green]}$line${paint[norm]}\n"               # Create line                           # | O_o
    home="${paint[bold]}${paint[blue]}$PWD${paint[norm]}"     # Home dir info                         # | o_o
    sign="${paint[green]}$line2$sign$line2${paint[norm]}\n"   # Hostname sign                         # | O_o
           #------+-----+-------+------+------------+-----+-------+--------+                          # | o_o
           # Line | O_o |homedir|Spaces| Git status | Date|  o_O  |  Line  |                          # | o_O
           #------+-----+-------+------+------------+-----+-------+--------+                          # | O_O
    printf "$sign $(face) $home %${S}s ${git_clr[*]} $date $(face) \n$line" # Final info string       # | O_o
}                                                                                                     # | O_o
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ o_o
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\n$(info)\n$ '                                                 # | º_O
                                                                                                      # | o_º
case "$TERM" in xterm*|rxvt*)                                                                         # | O_o
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)} ${faces[$[RANDOM % $facesN]]} \w\a\]$PS1";;        # | O_º
esac                                                                                                  # | o_O
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ O_o
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm pretty noobish with terminal. Am I supposed to copy/paste everything to my bashrc file?

Comment: @tableguarder the whole script is an installer it'll add all to your `~/.bashrc` or remove if you run it with `--remove` option.